# Any experience with Metwood joist reinforcers?

Tags: plumbing, joists, cutting

Does anyone in the group have experience using the following product from Metwood to reinforce joists that had to be to cut to route plumbing drains/pipes?

https://www.metwood.com/product/1-reinforcer/

This product lets you make a larger sized hole in joists than what what would otherwise be allowed by code.

The product doesn't seem to be widely available so hoping to get feedback (positive or negative) from those that have used it and are familiar with it.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you out [Metwood](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171979/how-to-cut-hole-larger-than-1-3-of-joist/172031#172031)

Comment: I have used them in several cases, I think they are two short but the building inspector required them instead of a longer steel and bolted plate set,   I did not have an engineering stamp. The metwood bracket was way cheaper than a stamped plan,  so-their plates passed , used in the same floor plan & reversed plans and did not have to revise the work on later builds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How many conseutive joists did u need to go through? In our care we need to through five joists (2x10) in the same line. Any concerns with the holes being in a straight line or would we need to run them at a diagonal? Appreciate any insights...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link provided by @Jack ([How to cut hole larger than 1/3 of joist?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171979/how-to-cut-hole-larger-than-1-3-of-joist/172031#172031)), but note that the only entity that matters is your AHJ.

Bring them the engineering specs from Metwood (https://www.metwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/CCRR-0279.pdf) and see if the answer is yes/no/need-more-information.

Comment: The engineer’s stamp is the big deal. I had double plated and bolted a similar job it failed , got these much lighter and shorter plated and they were cheaper than a stamp. I told the inspector this was crazy but he signed off on 3 homes with these.+